# Does Streams API functionality overlap with Spring Integration?

Tags: java, spring, java-stream, spring-integration

When introducing parallel processing to an application where multiple save entity calls are being made, I see prior dev has chosen to do it via Spring Integration using `split().channel(MessageChannels.executor(Executors.newfixedThreadPool(10))).handle("saveClass","saveMethod").aggregate().get()` - where this method is mapped to a requestChannel using @Gateway annotation. My question is this task seems to be simpler to do using the parallelStream() and forEach() method. Does IntergrationFlow provide any benefit in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really do a plain in-memory data processing where Java's `Stream` API is enough, then indeed you don't need the whole messaging solution like Spring Integration. But if you deal with distributed requirements to process data from different systems, like from HTTP to Apache Kafka or DB, then it is better to use some tool which allows you smoothly to connect everything together. Also: no one stops you to use `Stream` API in the Spring Integration application. In the end all your code is Java anyway. Please, learn more what is EIP and why we would need a special framework to implement this messaging-based solutions: https://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/